# Reading URLS in JSON api with swift

Tags: swift, url

For work we have a third party company which supply a JSON api for some functionality. The JSON contains urls which I try to map in my code with `URL(string: ...)` but this fails on some urls which have spaces.

For example:

```
var str = "https://google.com/article/test test.html"

let url = URL(string: str) //nil
```

Should I ask the third party to encode their URLs ?

Is this normal or should I try to add encoding myself? 
Encoding myself is hard I think because the path should be encoded different from the query and the host shouldn't be encoded etc.

Or am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 1):

If the URL contains spaces in its `path`, escape the characters with `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters` passing the `urlPathAllowed` character set:

```
let str = "https://google.com/article/test test.html"
if let escapedString = str.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed),
    let url = URL(string:escapedString) {
    print(url)
} else {
    print("url \(str) could not be encoded")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What I would do if I were you, is to split the string up on the space, try converting each of the elements to a url, and when that works save it in your variable.

```
var str = "https://google.com/article/test test.html"
var url: URL? = nil
for urlString in str.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines) {
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    if url != nil {
        break
    }
}
// url might be nil here, so test for value before using it
```

If each URL that you get from the API is in the format in your example, you can instead just grab the first element after spitting the string.

```
var str = "https://google.com/article/test test.html"
if let urlString = str.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines).first {
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
}
// url might be nil here, so test for value before using it
```

Comment: The specified URL is the correct URL. The space could be a %20 and it would be fine. Your answer would maybe give me an url but not the correct one.

Comment: @ScareCrow you can split strings on string values as well, so you could split on "%20" instead.